# isset is not working in laravel

Tags: laravel, isset

I am sending a variable from controller to a view.

```
$message = "Thanks for Contacting";

 return redirect('services')->with($message);
```

HTML

```
 @isset ($message)
 <a style="color: red;"> {{$message}} </a>
@endisset
```

But it shows en error, because when the first `services` is loaded from this route
`Route::get('/services', function () {
    return view('services');
});`

There's no variable,so it gives en error. Please let me know what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use it with @if, 
Try this:

```
@if(session()->has('message'))
 <a style="color: red;"> {{ session('message')}} </a>
@endif
```

and also change your controller like this:

```
return redirect('services')->with('message', $message);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. It seem to be working, as no error appeared, but message does not appear.

Comment: @AkAk glad to help

Comment: why message does not appear in the tag?

Comment: you mean this part: `<a style="color: red;"> {{$message}} </a>` ?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is how you're passing the variable to your view.

the correct way is:

```
return view('services')->with('message', $message);
```

or

```
return view('services')->withMessage($message);
```

or

```
return view('services', ['message' => $message]);
```

or

```
return view('services', compact('message'));
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable that set in `redirect()->with()` will saved to sessions variable, so to access it just call `session()` helper. Example:

```
@if (session('message'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{ session('message') }}
    </div>
@endif
```

More explanation:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/redirects#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data